# Select a posts with specific tags using Yii activeRecord

Tags: activerecord, yii

I have a typical setup with models for post, tag, and a postTag (an associative model/table), as follows:

Post
id, title

Tag, 
id, name

PostTag
id, post_id, tag_id

Can anyone tell me how to structure an activeRecord statement to get posts that have multiple specific tags associated with them?  For example, I might want all posts that have tags named 'foo' AND 'bar'.  The key is the AND. It's easy to get posts with 'foo' or 'bar'

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try somthing like:

```
Post.joins(:tags).where(tags: {name: ["foo","bar"]})
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a Yii solution. I'm guessing this is Ruby/rails.